# Show that there exist $K_0 = \mathbb Q ⊆ K_1 ⊆ K_2 ⊆ K_3 ⊆ K_4 = L$ , where, for $i = 1, . . . , 4$ , $|K_i : K_{i−1}| = 3$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, normal-extension

> Let $\mathbb Q ⊆ L$ be fields. Assume that $L$ is a normal extension of $\mathbb Q$ and
> $|L : \mathbb Q| = 81$. Show that there exist intermediate fields $K_1$, $K_2$, and $K_3$
> with $K_0 = \mathbb Q ⊆ K_1 ⊆ K_2 ⊆ K_3 ⊆ K_4 = L$ , where, for $i = 1, . . . , 4$ , $|K_i : K_{i−1}| = 3$.

$|X : Y|$ means degree of an extension.
Generaly let R be a commutative ring with identity, and let $F ⊆ R$ be a field. Consider $R$ a vector space over $F$. The dimension of this vector space is denoted by $|R : F|$ or $dim_F (R)$. If $F ⊆ E$ are
fields, then $|E : F|$ is called the degree of the field extension.

This is a homework question of mine: Exercise 26.1.7, from Shahriari, Algebra in Action.
I don't know how to start. I think I Should be use the tower rule; But how?!

**Tower rule**: Let F, K, and E be fields with F ⊆ K ⊆ E. Assume that
|K : F| and |E : K| are finite. Then |E : F| = |E : K| |K : F|.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: This is the sort of exercise where you will need some heavy machinery. Exactly which theorems you are allowed to use will depend on your course material. Look back over all the theorems. One of them will be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the degree of the extension is $81=3^4$ and it's Galois then the Galois group has order 81. So the second Sylow's theorem guarantees that there exist some subgroups $H_1,H_2,H_3$ whose orders are $3,9,27$  respectively, which verifies that $H_i\trianglelefteq H_{i+1}$ . The second fundamental theorem of Galois theory also guarantees that there exist some Galois extensions $K_1|\mathbb{Q},K_2|\mathbb{Q}, K_3|\mathbb{Q}$ whose degrees are $3,9,27$  respectively. So you have the extensions tower  $$K_0 = \mathbb Q ⊆ K_1 ⊆ K_2 ⊆ K_3 ⊆ K_4 = L$$ , where, for $i = 1, . . . , 4$ , $|K_i : K_{i−1}| = 3$.